# Testing - Can't resolve all parameters for (ClassName)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, angular2-testing, angular2-injection

### Context

I created an `ApiService` class to be able to handle our custom API queries, while using our own serializer + other features.

`ApiService`'s constructor signature is:

```js
constructor(metaManager: MetaManager, connector: ApiConnectorService, eventDispatcher: EventDispatcher);
```

- `MetaManager` is an injectable service that handles api's metadatas.
- `ApiConnectorService` is a service which is wrapping `Http` to add our custom headers and signature system.
- `EventDispatcher` is basically Symfony's event dispatcher system, in typescript.

### Problem

When I test the `ApiService`, I do an initialization in `beforeEach`:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports  : [
            HttpModule
        ],
        providers: [
            ApiConnectorService,
            ApiService,
            MetaManager,
            EventDispatcher,
            OFF_LOGGER_PROVIDERS
        ]
    });
}));
```

and it works fine.

Then I add my second spec file, which is for `ApiConnectorService`, with this `beforeEach`:

```js
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports  : [HttpModule],
        providers: [
            ApiConnectorService,
            OFF_LOGGER_PROVIDERS,
            AuthenticationManager,
            EventDispatcher
        ]
    });
}));
```

And all the tests fail with this error:

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApiService: (MetaManager, ?, EventDispatcher).

- If I remove `api-connector-service.spec.ts` (`ApiConnectorService`'s spec file) from my loaded tests, `ApiService`'s tests will succeed.
- If I remove `api-service.spec.ts` (`ApiService`'s spec file) from my loaded tests, `ApiConnectorService`'s tests will succeed.

Why do I have this error? It seems like the context between my two files are in conflict and I don't know why and how to fix this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because the `Http` service can't be resolved from the `HttpModule`, in a test environment. It is dependent on the platform browser. You shouldn't even be trying to to make XHR calls anyway during the tests.

For this reason, Angular provides a `MockBackend` for the `Http` service to use. We use this mock backend to subscribe to connections in our tests, and we can mock the response when each connection is made.

Here is a short complete example you can work off of

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { async, inject, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import {
  Http, HttpModule, XHRBackend, ResponseOptions,
  Response, BaseRequestOptions
} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
class SomeService {
  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getSomething(url) {
 return this._http.get(url).map(res => res.text());
  }
}

describe('service: SomeService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   providers: [
  {
    provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
   return new Http(backend, options);
    },
    deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
  },
  MockBackend,
  BaseRequestOptions,
  SomeService
   ]
 });
  });

  it('should get value',
 async(inject([SomeService, MockBackend],
     (service: SomeService, backend: MockBackend) => {

 backend.connections.subscribe((conn: MockConnection) => {
   const options: ResponseOptions = new ResponseOptions({body: 'hello'});
   conn.mockRespond(new Response(options));
 });

 service.getSomething('http://dummy.com').subscribe(res => {
   console.log('subcription called');
   expect(res).toEqual('hello');
 });
  })));
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions` instead of `{ provide: MockBackend, useClass: MockBackend },
        { provide: BaseRequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions },`. Aren't these two already provided by `HttpModule` (I'm pretty sure they are). Also `providers: [
        {
          provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
            return new Http(backend, options);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },` can be shortened to `{provide: XHRBackend: useExisting: MockBackend}`

Comment: So `providers: [{provide: XHRBackend: useExisting: MockBackend}, SomeService]` should give you the same result.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah you're right. I previously was using `XHRBackend` as the token, but I forgot I was injecting `MockBackend` type. So I changed it to `MockBackend` token. Wasn't thinking about style at the time, it was just a quick fix at the time I was testing.

Comment: As far as I remember the docs at Angular.io also show this long way. Your answer is fine. Just wanted to point it out. I have seen many examples where people use way too complicated configuration and then complain DI is cumbersome ;-)

Comment: So why do I get ApiConnectorService parameter not resolved? and why only when I start both tests?

Comment: Maybe because you trying to inject the apiservice and not the connector service, and error tells you what missing from  the service you are trying to inject.

Comment: Check the example ;) it's what I'm injecting. I changed HttpModule for a MockBackend and tried this way, still having the same error.

Comment: Can you post a complete example. Enough to reproduce the problem. Something like I did above.

Comment: I tried to create a complete example using the quickstart template, seems like I can't. The issue must be from my code but it's really too heavy to paste it here. Since the providers are all good and I provide a good Http now (with MockBackend) I don't see where this can come from...

Comment: What I would is just add stripped down versions of the classes with only the constructor and a single method to test. The problem is the injection, which can be reproduced without anything else in the classes. If you get it to work with the stripped down versions, start adding things until it breaks. Then you know the problem.

Comment: You can work off of this https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/2cce26fe4c9a3e73b8c8cbaa0fd738be, which works fine

Comment: I just came across this https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/1301#issuecomment-233578238 and thought about you. A shot in the dark, but could this be a possible issue?

Comment: @peeskillet this is exactly the problem I had, I just came here to say it and I saw your comment... :D

Comment: My service constructor looks like `constructor(private http: Http, baseName: string) {` , so where I need to modify in the above code?

Answer (score 24):

### Using Jest?

In case anyone gets here AND you're using Jest to test your Angular app (hopefully we're a growing minority), you will run into this error if you are not emitting decorators (`"emitDecoratorMetadata":true`).  You'll need to update your `tsconfig.spec.json` file so it looks like:

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Nothing in the error message to help figure this out.  The key is "emitDecoratorMetadata": true

Answer (score 9):

The issue wasn't really solved in the chosen answer, which is really just a recommendation for writing tests, but rather in the comments, and you have to follow a link and search for it there. Since I had another issue with the same error, I'll add both solutions here.

1. Solution to the OP's issue:

If you have a barrel (index.ts or multi export file) like this:

```js
export * from 'my.component' // using my.service via DI
export * from 'my.service'
```

Then you could get an error like `EXCEPTION: Can't resolve all parameters for MyComponent: (?)`.

To fix it, you have to export the service before the component:

```js
export * from 'my.service'
export * from 'my.component' // using my.service via DI
```

2. Solution to my issue:

The same error can happen due to a `circular dependency` which causes an `undefined` service import. To check, `console.log(YourService)` after importing it (in your test file - where the issue is happening). If it's undefined, you may have made an index.ts file (barrel) exporting both the service and the file using it (component/effect/whatever you're testing) - by importing the service from the index file where both are exported (making it full circle).

Find that file and import the service you need directly from `your.service.ts` file instead of the index.

Answer (score 1):

**[JEST and ANGULAR]**

Also, the problem may occur when you use an external module and you do not import it but use it on your service.

Ex:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import <ALL needed> from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { SettingsService } from '../../../app/core/services/settings/settings.service';


describe('SettingsService', () => {
  let service: SettingsService;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        SettingsService,
        // <All needed>
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject<SettingsService>(SettingsService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Errors will get you nowhere ...
But, if you do that this way:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { SettingsService } from '../../../app/core/services/settings/settings.service';


describe('SettingsService', () => {
  let service: SettingsService;

  beforeAll(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()], // <---
      providers: [
        SettingsService
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject<SettingsService>(SettingsService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

**[JEST and ANGULAR]**

In my case, the root cause is the **circular dependency**, but not the "import service from index" situation. And `ng build <project> --prod` didn't find the "circular dependency".

Solution:

In the service/component, injecting `Injector` and `injector.get(Service)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Jest and Angular] In my case I was creating a dummy component class that inherited a base component which was what I was interested in testing. The problem was that it was set to use the default constuctor, so TestBed didn't have a chance to inject a stubService for me. This is what the code looks like:

```js
class DummyComponent extends MyBaseComponent {
  constructor(localizationService: LocalizationService) {
    super(localizationService) // this is needed constructor
  }
...
let fixture: ComponentFixture<DummyComponent>
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [DummyComponent],
      imports: [{ provide: MyService, useValue: MyStubService}],
    })
  })
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DummyComponent) // <-- It was failing here
}
```

Looking back it seems more obvious because a concrete class will have to define the constructor to get the service. I just thought that would be the default constructor.