# Angular 2 - Mocking - response is null

Tags: unit-testing, angular, mocking, jasmine

*Angular 2.0.0 - Ionic 2 RC0 - Npm 3.10.8 - Node v4.5.0 - Karma 1.3.0 - Jasmine 2.5.2*

*previous question: [Angular 2 -- Mocking - No Provider for HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891904/angular-2-mocking-no-provider-for-http/39892530#39892530)*

---

I'm now getting a new error while executing `npm test` : `null is not an object (evaluating '_this.events.length')`

Which is triggered by this code: `if(this.events.length > 0){` in EventsPage which means my response I set in `events.spec.ts` is somehow not properly returned.

I'm new to mocking Angular2 so it's moest likely a rookie mistake.

(changed some code from previous question, so I'll repost them)

**EventPage**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, Loading, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { APICaller } from '../../services/apicaller.service';
import { EventDetailComponent } from '../event-detail/event-detail.component';
import { Event } from '../../models/event.model';

/*
  Class for Evenementen Overzicht.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'events-component',
  templateUrl: 'events.component.html',
  providers: [ APICaller ]
})

 /** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    export class EventsPage {

    //list of all events
    public events : Array<Event>;
    //the event that has been clicked on the page
    public selectedEvent : Event;
    //boolean to show 'no events' error message
    public noEvents:boolean;

     /** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

      constructor(public navCtrl : NavController, public apiCaller:APICaller, public loadingCtrl : LoadingController) {
        //retrieve all events --> async method, can't use this.events yet.
        this.getEvents();
      }

      /** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

      /**Get Events - Sets the 'events' variable to all events found by the API. */
      getEvents(){
        //setup a loadingscreen (broke testing so removed for now)
       // let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        //  content: "Loading..."
       // }); 
        //present the loadingscreen
       // loading.present();

        //reset the noEvents boolean.
        this.noEvents = true;

        //call the api and get all events
        this.apiCaller.getEvents()
        .subscribe(response => {

          console.log("RESP:"+response);
          //response is list of events
          this.events = response;
          //if the event is not empty, set noEvents to false.

          if(this.events.length > 0){ //<----------------------------FAILS HERE
            this.noEvents = false;
          }
          //close the loading message.
         // loading.dismiss();
        });
      }
    }
```

**EventPage -- Spec**

```
import { TestBed, inject, tick, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Http, ConnectionBackend, Response, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { mockNavController, mockApp } from 'ionic-angular/util/mock-providers';
import { EventsPage } from './events.component';
import { MockAPICaller } from '../../services/mocks/apicaller.service';
import { APICaller } from '../../services/apicaller.service';


describe('Component: EventsComponent', () => {
  let mockAPICaller : MockAPICaller = new MockAPICaller();
  let loadingCtrl : LoadingController = new LoadingController(this);

  beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [EventsPage],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
      {provide: APICaller, useValue: mockAPICaller},
      {provide: NavController, useValue: mockNavController },
      {provide: LoadingController, useValue: loadingCtrl},
    ],
    imports: [FormsModule]
  });

  TestBed.overrideComponent(EventsPage,{
    set: {
      providers: [
        {provide: APICaller, useValue: mockAPICaller}
      ]
    }
  });
  });


  it('should return all events', () => {

      let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventsPage);
      let eventsPage = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();

      mockAPICaller.setResponse(JSON.stringify(`[{
        id: 4,
        title: 'Weekend',
        eventdate: '24/09/2016',
        kind: 'closed',
        startingtime: '18:00',
        endtime: '21:00',
        description: 'Go Home'
      }]`));
      eventsPage.getEvents();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      console.log(eventsPage.events);

  });
});
```

**MockAPICaller**

```
import { SpyObject } from './helper';
import { APICaller } from '../apicaller.service';
import Spy = jasmine.Spy;

export class MockAPICaller extends SpyObject {
    getEventsSpy: Spy;
    searchEventSpy:Spy;
    getParticipantSpy:Spy;
    getEventParticipantsSpy:Spy;
    searchEventParticipantSpy:Spy;
    addNewCommentSpy:Spy;
    updateCommentSpy:Spy;
    deleteCommentSpy:Spy;
    getUsernameSpy:Spy;
    presentSuccessMessageSpy:Spy;

    fakeResponse:any;

    constructor(){
        super( APICaller );
        this.fakeResponse = null;
        this.getEventsSpy = this.spy('getEvents').andReturn(this);
        this.searchEventSpy = this.spy('searchEvent').andReturn(this);
        this.getParticipantSpy = this.spy('getParticipant').andReturn(this);
        this.getEventParticipantsSpy = this.spy('getEventParticipant').andReturn(this);
        this.searchEventParticipantSpy = this.spy('searchEventParticipant').andReturn(this);
        this.addNewCommentSpy = this.spy('addNewComment').andReturn(this);
        this.updateCommentSpy = this.spy('updateComment').andReturn(this);
        this.deleteCommentSpy = this.spy('deleteComment').andReturn(this);
        this.getUsernameSpy = this.spy('getUsername').andReturn(this);
        this.presentSuccessMessageSpy = this.spy('presentSuccessMessage').andReturn(this);
    }

    subscribe(callback: any){
        callback(this.fakeResponse);
    }

    setResponse(json:any):void{
        this.fakeResponse = json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the response on the mock before creating the component. You are calling `getEvents` in the component constructor, and the mock hasn't set the data yet.

```
it('should return all events', () => {
  mockAPICaller.setResponse(JSON.stringify(`[{
    id: 4,
    title: 'Weekend',
    eventdate: '24/09/2016',
    kind: 'closed',
    startingtime: '18:00',
    endtime: '21:00',
    description: 'Go Home'
  }]`));
  let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EventsPage);
  let eventsPage = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  eventsPage.getEvents();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  console.log(eventsPage.events);
});
```

Comment: thanks again, would you maybe also know how to resolve this error? : `undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'response.json()')`

Comment: Where are you getting that?

Comment: Ah it's not in this code, I figured the mockApi was returning just the json stirng, so in my subscribe of `EventPage` I added `.json()` to the end of the response since I'm returning a Json string

Comment: So `this.events = response.json();` instead of `this.events = response;`

Comment: Just have the mock object have a single `json()` function that returns the object. `setResponse({ json: function() { return theObject; } })`

Comment: Ah found a workaround that involved not having to refactor my entire code, thanks anyway :)