# Error: No provider for Http! karma tests for components

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

**what i have** : Service provider depends on Http, need to be tested

**MyService.ts :**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
 constructor(private http: Http) {
 }

 someFunction() {
   return this.http.get(URL)
   .map((res: Response) => {
    res.json();
   });
 }
}
```

**MyComponent.ts:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {}
}
```

When i run the ng test , the error

**No http provider for myComponent appears
, MyService should be created**

MyComponent.spec.ts :

```
 describe('MyComponent', () => {
   let component: MyComponent;
   let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

   beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
         HttpModule
       ],
       declarations: [ MyComponent],
       providers: [
         MockBackend,
         BaseRequestOptions,
         {
           provide: HttpClient,
           useFactory: (backendInstance: MockBackend, defaultOptions:           BaseRequestOptions) => {
             return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
           },
           deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
         },
         MyService
       ]
     })
     .compileComponents();

   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
     component = fixture.componentInstance;
     // fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should be created', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
 });
```

**what i tried**
All what i tried is there ! i also read about MockBackend and buid it in the service as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39472364/testing-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-classname) shows ! but it didnt worked for me !

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i was missing the import **HTTP module** , **provide HTTP , ConnectionBackend** in the service.spec.ts file, not only in the component.spec.ts file.

Comment: +1. Thanks saved me an hour . why do we need to include HTTPModule in service spec even it has mentioned in the component spec. If service of the component will be spied in component spec then why we have explicitly import in service spec ?