# Issue with CustomEvent object in angular during jasmine test cases

Tags: angular, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to test an angular application using Jasmine which I encountered a method having CustomEvent interface as an argument.

```
 beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
      declarations: [ MyComponent],
      providers: [MyService,CustomEvent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

it('should return void if submitted without selecting user', () => {
    console.log("promise" + fixture.componentInstance.submitForm());// submit form is a method from the MyComponent class
  })
```

When I run this test case I am getting the below error message.
**Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomEvent: (?).**

Also the same occurs for Event as well. Please let me know what to add inorder to resolve this

Comment: You're getting this error most likely because `CustomEvent` has services (or a service because of the error showing one question mark) it depends on and it needs to be provided as well. I would personally mock `CustomEvent` or external services in a unit test. Can you show the constructor of `CustomEvent`?

Comment: CustomEvent is an interface available under node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts

Comment: Try removing `CustomEvent` from `providers` array.

Comment: we will get the below error if we remove that
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[CustomEvent -> CustomEvent]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CustomEvent!

Comment: I think you're facing a variation of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39483673/7365461. Also check out the 3rd post there as well. I would remove `HttpClientModule` and use `HttpClientTestingModule`. I think we can't use `HttpClientModule` in a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

After some research below approach is working fine

Create event object as below and pass it to the method required
var event = new CustomEvent("test", {
detail: 'test'
});